# Highlight unused variables and imports is not working properly

Tags: visual-studio-code, highlight

VSCode May 2018 (version 1.24, MacOs)

Feature: [Highlight unused variables and imports](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_24#_highlight-unused-variables-and-imports)

### Description of the feature:

Unused variables, parameters, and imports are now greyed out in JavaScript and TypeScript.

### My problem:

I created a simple `test.js` file:

```
var var1  // not used => should be greyed out
var var2 = 2
var var3

var3 = var2 + 2
console.log(var3)
```

The variable is not greyed out on my screen.
I am using the theme `Dark+`.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This feature only works in a file that contains at least one `require`, `import`, or `export` statement.

If I create a `test.js` file like yours, I experience the same issue.  However, placing any of these lines at the top of the file fixes it:

`require('');`

or

`import { } from "";`

or

`module.exports.mymodule = {};`

---

This is [apparently by design, and not a bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/51882).

Comment: I have the same issue but adding the lines that Mike specified makes no difference.

Comment: @RichardShergold This feature also requires Typescript 2.9+.  Is your project using an older version of Typescript?

Comment: Thanks Mike - that could be the issue

Comment: I also have the same issue with the latest VSCode (1.30.1) on macOS Mojave. I should note though that on VSCode Insiders this works fine, so I'm hoping it will be fixed in the next release.

Comment: Same issue what's going on with this why doesn't such feature exist?

Comment: this used to work automatically for me and now all of a sudden it's gone.....