# Dim out unused C++ variables in VS Code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have setup VS Code with the line

```
"editor.showUnused": true
```

However, code still looks like

[image: code that does not dim out unused variable "foobar"]

I added `*foobar` myself and it seems to not be displayed in a dimmed out fashion.

Why not?

If VS Code does not have C/C++ support of showing unused variables in the editor with an alternate color, is there some other IDE in linux that has?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50758454/highlight-unused-variables-and-imports-is-not-working-properly

Answer (score 2):

Language extensions are responsible for determining which variables are unused. Here, this would be the [C++ extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools). This is because detecting unused variable requires understanding of the structure and semantics of your program

I do not believe that that the C++ extension currently supports fading out unused variables. Please [file a feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools) if you would like to see this supported

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using [the cpptools extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools)...

For problem underlining (squiggly underlines), you can configure a build task and set the problem matcher property to some appropriate value. See also [Unused variables are not highlighted in the editor
#6588](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/6588).

For dimmed text, at the time of this writing, there is an open feature-request issue ticket: [Dimming of Unused Variables
#10490](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/10490). Give it a thumbs up to increase its prioritization level, and subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments there like "+1" / "bump".